# string count on oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using following query:

```
SELECT 
  CURRENT_AFFAIRS_ID,
  IMPORTANT_EXAM 
FROM CURRENT_AFFAIRS_LANGUAGE 
WHERE CURRENT_AFFAIRS_ID IN (
  1362544236,
  1363764599,
  1363670667,
  1363516827,
  1363500146)  
AND IMPORTANT_EXAM IS NOT NULL 
AND IS_ACTIVE = 1 
AND IS_DELETED = 0
```

to display following data:

```
1363764599  Civil Services Exam, SSC Exams
1363670667  Bank Exams, SSC Exams
1363516827  Bank Exams, Civil Services Exam, SSC Exams
1363500146  Civil Services Exam, SSC Exams
```

My requirement is to count number of occurrences of string separated by comma (eg. Civil Services Exam)

I tried to do this by java coding.

But it seems too much complicated work.

Can it be possible using any function of oracle or on the database side ?

Comment: How far did you get with Java?

Answer (score 3):

From 11g you can try [REGEXP_COUNT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions135.htm)

```
SELECT 
  CURRENT_AFFAIRS_ID,
  IMPORTANT_EXAM ,
  regexp_count(IMPORTANT_EXAM , '[^,]+')
FROM CURRENT_AFFAIRS_LANGUAGE 
WHERE CURRENT_AFFAIRS_ID IN (
  1362544236,
  1363764599,
  1363670667,
  1363516827,
  1363500146)  
AND IMPORTANT_EXAM IS NOT NULL 
AND IS_ACTIVE = 1 
AND IS_DELETED = 0
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c66c8/1)

Answer (score 1):

As a quick-and-dirty option you can use `regexp_replace` to strip out everything in the string except the commas, count those and add one. That assumes the string are well-formed.

```
SELECT 
  CURRENT_AFFAIRS_ID,
  IMPORTANT_EXAM,
  LENGTH(regexp_replace(IMPORTANT_EXAM, '[^,]', '')) + 1 AS EXAMS
FROM CURRENT_AFFAIRS_LANGUAGE 
WHERE CURRENT_AFFAIRS_ID IN (
  1362544236,
  1363764599,
  1363670667,
  1363516827,
  1363500146)  
AND IMPORTANT_EXAM IS NOT NULL 
AND IS_ACTIVE = 1 
AND IS_DELETED = 0;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ec51/1).

**Edit**: if you are on 11g then `regexp_count` is even better, as A.B.Cade shows - use that if you can. This `regexp_replace` option will work from 10g, so I'll leave it here for now...

I'm not sure why you're storing multiple values in one string though. You should move the exams to a separate table, and then have a mapping table that shows which exams are available in which languages.